# What is the fastest MD5 sum calculator?

Tags: ubuntu, hashing, md5

I tested the speed of `md5sum` on a few Ubuntu 8.04 servers

- Pentium III 700 MHz: *52 MB/s*
- Atom 1.6 GHz, 32-bit: *119 MB/s*
- Core 2 (Yorkfield) 2.5GHz, 32-bit: *194 MB/s*
- Core 2 (Yorkfield) 2.5GHz, 64-bit: *222 MB/s*

Then I downloaded a tool (by `apt-get install`) called `md5deep` and found that it's roughly 20% faster (as tested on the 32-bit Core 2 server). This makes me feel that the "vanilla" `md5sum` included in Ubuntu isn't the fastest one.

Questions:

2. Other than `md5deep`, are you aware of any MD5 calculators that are potentially faster than `md5sum`? (Answers for software from other OS are also welcomed.)
3. If I want to compile `md5sum` myself, what compiler options would you suggest for the Core 2 server? (note: `gcc` 4.2.4 in Ubuntu 8.04 does not seem to support `-march=core2`)

---

Edit: I downloaded and compiled [coreutils-8.4](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.4.tar.gz) on the 64-bit Core 2 server and the speed increased to *320 MB/s*... Unbelievable!

FYI, the one included in Ubuntu 8.04 is coreutils-6.10.

Is it safe to replace coreutils with a newer version?

Comment: Usually md5sum is faster than my disk...eg I don't have a HDD that can read at 200MB/sec, so a faster than that md5sum doesn't help any. Do you have a really fast SSD RAID array? Or are you running md5sum on files stored on a ramdisk (tmpfs) or something?

Comment: At first I used a 1GB file of random bytes, loaded completely in the memory cache. Then I found that the `md5sum` speed is the same if I pipe null bytes into `md5sum` on the fly. I decided to use the latter method so that servers without 1GB RAM can also be tested.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how OpenSSL's md5 implementation compares to the others you've benchmarked.

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd chime in to add some updated speed benchmarks.

Using md5sum on Ubuntu 10.10, which uses coreutils 8.5:

- Core 2 Quad (Kentsfield) 2.66GHz, 64-bit: 404 MB/s